# I want to run except query with row count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to do a count for both tables and then do a minus so result should be zero.  Can you please provide me right syntax? Thanks in advance I am using sql server and had the source table is in oracle and target teradata.
Currently I am using following syntax:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Table 1.[BATCH] except SELECT count (*) FROM table 2;
```

Comment: See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9627155/812933) for a solution that allows you to generate queries from the sys.* schema.  By generating the queries, you can include table name in the results. I can't really offer more advice right now because I'm not entirely clear what you are attempting to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

you can run your except query as a subquery

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   Table1
        EXCEPT
        SELECT *
        FROM   Table2) T
```

Comment: Thanks for reply .syntax is working is it possible to display table names

Comment: @user3803261, you mean table1 count, table2 count and minus count?

Comment: i am working on 400 tables ,i want result should be like             Table 1    0
Table 3    0
Table 10   0

Answer (score 0):

Just do two subqueries and subtract them:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Table1.[BATCH]) - (SELECT count (*) FROM table2);
```